# Angular UI buttons not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular UI, I already loaded dependencies and got the module `'ui.bootstrap''`.

Attempting to [imitate this](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons). This is what I'm trying:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label ng-model="reactionType" uib-btn-radio="left" uncheckable class="btn btn-sucess">Alegría</label>
      <label ng-model="reactionType" uib-btn-radio="middle" uncheckable class="btn btn-default">Tristeza</label>
      <label ng-model="reactionType" uib-btn-radio="right" uncheckable class="btn btn-default">Tristeza</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And got

[image]

so first button on the left keeps always checked while the others seem to be uncheckable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's super subtle, but you are missing the single quotes in the uib-btn-radio values.

> `ie: "'left'"`

Revised Code Below:

```
<label ng-model="reactionType" uib-btn-radio="'left'" uncheckable class="btn btn-default">Alegría</label>
<label ng-model="reactionType" uib-btn-radio="'middle'" uncheckable class="btn btn-default">Tristeza</label>
<label ng-model="reactionType" uib-btn-radio="'right'" uncheckable class="btn btn-default">Tristeza</label>
```

Comment: ouch! that's nasty. spent a few hours on this and would have never caught that. thanks!!